# ProGuard: When trying to shrink a library, it just gives me back my project files

Tags: scala, proguard

I need to shrink the Scala Library to only include the files required for my project (stayAway).

The problem is, it's just giving me back a jar with my project files in it; not the shrunk library. In the Input/Output menu, I've tried moving things around by every combination possible:

```
(Configuration used below)
1.
Programs Jars (PJ): Project Jar, Output Jar
Library Jars (LJ): Scala Library Jar, Java Library Jar
Yields: My original project files in a jar

2.
PJs: Project Jar, Scala Library Jar, Output Jar
LJs: Java Library Jar
Yields: My project files coupled with the entire Scala library in a jar

3.
PJs: Scala Library Jar, Output Jar
LJs: Project Files, Java Library Jar
Yields: The entire Scala library in a jar
```

I just want a shrunk Scala library jar! It seems to be completely disregarding my project files.

I'm using the following configuration (generated by the GUI):

```
-injars 'C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\stayAway'
-outjars 'C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\ProGuard Output\shrunkScalaLibrary.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\scala-library.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\rt.jar'

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontobfuscate
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-verbose
-ignorewarnings


-keep class stayAway.MainFrame

# Keep - Library. Keep all public and protected classes, fields, and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Remove - System method calls. Remove all invocations of System
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.System {
    public static long currentTimeMillis();
    static java.lang.Class getCallerClass();
    public static int identityHashCode(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.SecurityManager getSecurityManager();
    public static java.util.Properties getProperties();
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getenv(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String mapLibraryName(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}

# Remove - Math method calls. Remove all invocations of Math
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.Math {
    public static double sin(double);
    public static double cos(double);
    public static double tan(double);
    public static double asin(double);
    public static double acos(double);
    public static double atan(double);
    public static double toRadians(double);
    public static double toDegrees(double);
    public static double exp(double);
    public static double log(double);
    public static double log10(double);
    public static double sqrt(double);
    public static double cbrt(double);
    public static double IEEEremainder(double,double);
    public static double ceil(double);
    public static double floor(double);
    public static double rint(double);
    public static double atan2(double,double);
    public static double pow(double,double);
    public static int round(float);
    public static long round(double);
    public static double random();
    public static int abs(int);
    public static long abs(long);
    public static float abs(float);
    public static double abs(double);
    public static int max(int,int);
    public static long max(long,long);
    public static float max(float,float);
    public static double max(double,double);
    public static int min(int,int);
    public static long min(long,long);
    public static float min(float,float);
    public static double min(double,double);
    public static double ulp(double);
    public static float ulp(float);
    public static double signum(double);
    public static float signum(float);
    public static double sinh(double);
    public static double cosh(double);
    public static double tanh(double);
    public static double hypot(double,double);
    public static double expm1(double);
    public static double log1p(double);
}

# Remove - Number method calls. Remove all invocations of Number
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.* extends java.lang.Number {
    public static java.lang.String toString(byte);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(byte);
    public static byte parseByte(java.lang.String);
    public static byte parseByte(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Byte decode(java.lang.String);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Byte);
    public static java.lang.String toString(short);
    public static short parseShort(java.lang.String);
    public static short parseShort(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(short);
    public static java.lang.Short decode(java.lang.String);
    public static short reverseBytes(short);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Short);
    public static java.lang.String toString(int,int);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toOctalString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toBinaryString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toString(int);
    public static int parseInt(java.lang.String,int);
    public static int parseInt(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(int);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer);
    public static java.lang.Integer decode(java.lang.String);
    public static int highestOneBit(int);
    public static int lowestOneBit(int);
    public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int);
    public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(int);
    public static int bitCount(int);
    public static int rotateLeft(int,int);
    public static int rotateRight(int,int);
    public static int reverse(int);
    public static int signum(int);
    public static int reverseBytes(int);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Integer);
    public static java.lang.String toString(long,int);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toOctalString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toBinaryString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toString(long);
    public static long parseLong(java.lang.String,int);
    public static long parseLong(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(long);
    public static java.lang.Long decode(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String,long);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String,java.lang.Long);
    public static long highestOneBit(long);
    public static long lowestOneBit(long);
    public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(long);
    public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(long);
    public static int bitCount(long);
    public static long rotateLeft(long,int);
    public static long rotateRight(long,int);
    public static long reverse(long);
    public static int signum(long);
    public static long reverseBytes(long);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Long);
    public static java.lang.String toString(float);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(float);
    public static java.lang.Float valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Float valueOf(float);
    public static float parseFloat(java.lang.String);
    public static boolean isNaN(float);
    public static boolean isInfinite(float);
    public static int floatToIntBits(float);
    public static int floatToRawIntBits(float);
    public static float intBitsToFloat(int);
    public static int compare(float,float);
    public boolean isNaN();
    public boolean isInfinite();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Float);
    public static java.lang.String toString(double);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(double);
    public static java.lang.Double valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Double valueOf(double);
    public static double parseDouble(java.lang.String);
    public static boolean isNaN(double);
    public static boolean isInfinite(double);
    public static long doubleToLongBits(double);
    public static long doubleToRawLongBits(double);
    public static double longBitsToDouble(long);
    public static int compare(double,double);
    public boolean isNaN();
    public boolean isInfinite();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Double);
    public byte byteValue();
    public short shortValue();
    public int intValue();
    public long longValue();
    public float floatValue();
    public double doubleValue();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public int hashCode();
    public java.lang.String toString();
}

# Remove - String method calls. Remove all invocations of String
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.String {
    public static java.lang.String copyValueOf(char[]);
    public static java.lang.String copyValueOf(char[],int,int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(boolean);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char[]);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char[],int,int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(double);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(float);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(long);
    public boolean contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer);
    public boolean endsWith(java.lang.String);
    public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String);
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public boolean matches(java.lang.String);
    public boolean regionMatches(boolean,int,java.lang.String,int,int);
    public boolean regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int);
    public boolean startsWith(java.lang.String);
    public boolean startsWith(java.lang.String,int);
    public byte[] getBytes();
    public byte[] getBytes(java.lang.String);
    public char charAt(int);
    public char[] toCharArray();
    public int compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.String);
    public int hashCode();
    public int indexOf(int);
    public int indexOf(int,int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(int);
    public int lastIndexOf(int,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.CharSequence subSequence(int,int);
    public java.lang.String concat(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String replace(char,char);
    public java.lang.String replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String[] split(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String[] split(java.lang.String,int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
    public java.lang.String toLowerCase();
    public java.lang.String toLowerCase(java.util.Locale);
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public java.lang.String toUpperCase();
    public java.lang.String toUpperCase(java.util.Locale);
    public java.lang.String trim();
}

# Remove - StringBuffer method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuffer
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuffer {
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public char charAt(int);
    public int capacity();
    public int codePointAt(int);
    public int codePointBefore(int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
}

# Remove - StringBuilder method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuilder
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuilder {
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public char charAt(int);
    public int capacity();
    public int codePointAt(int);
    public int codePointBefore(int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FINALLY got it working after 7+ hours. I'll post what I did here, partially for my own future reference, partly to save anyone else from a headache and a wasted day.

1. I used the command line tool instead of the GUI. I don't know why it makes a difference, but it did.
2. I used the following for my config file (saved as config.pro):

   ```
   -injars ".\classes"(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
   -injars "C:\Users\Brendon\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.5.jar"(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
   -libraryjars "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib\rt.jar"
   -outjars "C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\shrunkScalaLibrary.jar"
   -dontnote
   -dontwarn
   -ignorewarnings
   -dontobfuscate
   -keep public class stayAway.MainFrame {
       public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   }
   ```

   - Change the first 2 `injar`s to parent folder of your class files (above your package folder), and the location of the scala library jar

     - I don't know what the "manifest" part in brackets is for. Most of this was copied from a generated .pro file from sbt that later failed because it didn't like my java version (Unsupported class version number [52.0])
     - I'll edit this if I figure out it's purpose, and if it's necessary.
   - `outjar` is just the output location
   - The warning suppressors are to allow it to output even when it gets caught on scala specific problems that aren't "fatal"
   - I used `-dontobfuscate` so I could look over the produced jar. It's not necessary, and seems to make your outputted jar bigger (~4x)
   - I don't know exactly what the final part is; it was generated. I'm guessing it's to keep your files untouched, but my project is an applet, so it doesn't have a main.
3. I copied config.pro and my class folder into the proguard lib folder (quick and dirty). The class folder should be above your package folder. In my case, this looked like:

   ```
   - classes
       - stayAway
           - (All my classes)
   ```
4. Using `shift + F10` I opened a command prompt to the current location (`proguard/lib`)
5. I ran the command `java -jar proguard.jar @config.pro`, which output:

   ```
   ProGuard, version 5.2
   Reading program directory  [C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\proguard\lib\classes] (filtered)
   Reading program jar [C:\Users\Brendon\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.5.jar] (filtered)

   Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib\rt.jar]
   Preparing output jar [C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\shrunkScalaLibrary.jar]
     Copying resources from program directory [C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\proguard\lib\classes] (filtered)
     Copying resources from program jar [C:\Users\Brendon\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.
   5.jar] (filtered)
   ```
6. PROFIT!

If you're having trouble, I'll probably vaguely remember what I did for awhile.

Good Luck

EDITS:

- Deleting the bracketed "manifest" parts makes the produced jar 2kb larger, but it still functions. I don't know what it's for.
- Deleting the `-keep` parts yields an error. I guess this defines the entry point into your program so it know what to keep. Like I said though, I'm making an applet, which doesn't have a `main`; so I don't know exactly what's going on here.